# ASPX Postback selectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, postback, selectedindexchanged

I am using an combobox with some values and `AutoPostBack = true`, the page does not refresh.

I have a `selectedIndexChanged` event as well.

I managed to get the `selectedValue` and I would like to show this in a `TextBox`.

In the `selectedIndexChanged` event I did:

```
textBox1.Text = selectedValue.ToString();
```

When I inspect this textbox element with `Google Chrome` I can see the value is set in the `TextBox`.

But in the browser the value isn't shown, still an empty `TextBox`.

Do you guys have any clue why this could happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the TextBox visible, you just don't see the new text in it?

Comment: @mason Yes the TextBox is visible of course, I inspected the element and the value is set.

Comment: You should create a [minimally verifiable and complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and post the code for that. You may be doing something that's causing this to happen that we can't see.

Comment: Can you provide the complte asp.net code?

Answer (score -1):

How do you populate items for ComboBox? If dynamically via On-Load event then make sure that method that adds items does not run on PostBack.

Comment: Why would this help? and the data is not bound via onload

Comment: The Onload gets only called with a if(IsPostBack)

Comment: @TheOddGuy - it would help because if OnLoad Event loads items into ComboBox it also resets SelectedIndex and SelecedValue property and your TextBox will not be passed correct value.

Comment: No it does not reset the selectedindex en selectedvalue.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your working code buddy.
Don't forget ToString method.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test2" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem>Item1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Item2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Item3</asp:ListItem>

        </asp:ComboBox>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="textBox1"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and code

```
public partial class Test2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
}
```